# jQuery reload function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

- Scrolling marquee content (with flexible length) makes a complete journey from right to left of the screen
- Once it has disappeared off the screen, bring up some generic messages
- In the background during generic messages, check for any new scrolling content and load it
- Only when the generic messages have finished displaying, start scrolling again (if there is new content), otherwise repeat the generic messages

http://jsfiddle.net/Vbmm5/

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.marquee = function(options) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var o = $.extend({}, $.fn.marquee.defaults, options),
                $this = $(this),
                $marqueeWrapper,
                containerWidth,
                animationCss,
                elWidth;
            o = $.extend({}, o, $this.data());
            o.gap = o.duplicated ? o.gap : 0;
            $this.wrapInner('<div class="js-marquee"></div>');
            var $el = $this.find('.js-marquee').css({
                'margin-right': o.gap, 
                'float':'left'
            });
            if(o.duplicated) {
                $el.clone().appendTo($this);
            }
            $this.wrapInner('<div style="width:100000px" class="js-marquee-wrapper"></div>');
            elWidth = $this.find('.js-marquee:first').width() + o.gap;
            $marqueeWrapper = $this.find('.js-marquee-wrapper');
            containerWidth = $this.width();
            o.speed = ((parseInt(elWidth,10) + parseInt(containerWidth,10)) / parseInt(containerWidth,10)) * o.speed;
            var animate = function() {
                if(!o.duplicated) {
                    $marqueeWrapper.css('margin-left', o.direction == 'left' ? containerWidth : '-' + elWidth + 'px');
                    animationCss = { 'margin-left': o.direction == 'left' ? '-' + elWidth + 'px' : containerWidth };
                }
                else {
                    $marqueeWrapper.css('margin-left', o.direction == 'left' ? 0 : '-' + elWidth + 'px');
                    animationCss = { 'margin-left': o.direction == 'left' ? '-' + elWidth + 'px' : 0 };
                }
                $marqueeWrapper.animate(animationCss, o.speed , 'linear', function(){
                    getUpdates();
                });
            };
            setTimeout(animate, o.delayBeforeStart);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(function(){
    $('#scrollerContent').marquee({
        speed: 3000,
        gap: 50,
        delayBeforeStart: 0,
        direction: 'right',
        duplicated: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
    });
});

function getUpdates()
{
    alert("Hello"); // This is where the jQuery get function would be to update the text
    alert("Show Details"); // This is where the generic details would be displayed
    marquee();
}
```

The problem is the scrolling element requires a width, which obviously changes with every new 'load' of messages. I tried putting the getUpdates() function inside the main jQuery function, which does work almost perfectly but doesn't update the containerWidth variable, so messages longer than the original start half-way through, and shorter messages take ages to appear.

What I need is for the whole of the function to be re-run, including the re-setting of the width after the #scrollerText paragraph has been changed.

How do I do this?

Comment: The marquee code is taken from http://jquery.aamirafridi.com/jquerymarquee/

Comment: If you had used console.log() instead of alert() you would have had the console open and seen

`Uncaught ReferenceError: marquee is not defined`

In getUpdates() you're calling a function marquee(); that does not exist. The script terminates there.

Comment: And I thought `<marquee>` was dead...

Comment: @DerFlatulator `<marquee>` is not being used.

Comment: Yes, but it is being essentially replicated by JS.

Comment: @popnoodles I know - I was hoping (I'm still learning jQuery) that the entire function was called marquee, based on the line "$.fn.marquee = function(options) ..." - and that the entire function (including re-setting of the containerWidth variable) would be re-executed.

Comment: @DerFlatulator yes it is. Are you suggesting it shouldn't be?

Comment: @popnoodles most people cannot tolerate marquees.

Comment: @DerFlatulator And you think that helps answer the question how?

Comment: @DerFlatulator This will eventually be used on television displaying tweets and facebook messages scrolling along the bottom of the screen. The <marquee> HTML tag is quite jerky, hence the replacement with jQuery which is much smoother. If you can think of any other way of having scrolling text, I'd love to hear it! Just because a HTML element is considered old-fashioned, doesn't mean there aren't still uses for it - and in some cases (like this one) there is simply no alternative.

Comment: Fair enough, the TV use case is a good one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had used `console.log()` instead of `alert()` you would have had the console open and seen

`Uncaught ReferenceError: marquee is not defined`

In `getUpdates()` you're calling a function `marquee();` that does not exist. The script terminates there.

Go back a few steps (undoing what you've removed) and where the code triggers the animation, add the code to update the text before that, or if you're getting data you need to wrap that bit of code.

So, if you were getting data from the server, theurl.php would return text new text and nothing else. Move the code that triggers the animation to go again within the $.get callback function.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vbmm5/4/

```
$marqueeWrapper.animate(animationCss, o.speed , 'linear', function(){
    // clear the text to prevent it from hanging at the end of the 
    // marquee while the script gets new data from the server 
    $this.find('#scrollerText').text('');
    // get new text
    $.get('theurl.php', function(response){
        $this.find('#scrollerText').text(response);
        // update the width
        elWidth = $this.find('.js-marquee:first').width(); 
        //fire event
        $this.trigger('finished');
        //animate again
        if(o.pauseOnCycle) {
            setTimeout(animate, o.delayBeforeStart);
        }
        else {
            animate();
        }
    });
});
```

(the URL and post data in the example on jsfiddle is jsfiddle's way of returning html)

I've used `$this.find('#scrollerText').text(response);` even though there should be only one id and `$('#scrollerText').text(response);` would be fine. If you were to have multiple marquees you would target each marquee's text using `$this.find`, so if you want more than one use classes instead `$this.find('.scrollerText').text(response);`

Comment: thanks, however in your jsFiddle the problem still exists. The second scroll starts half-way through, i.e. doesn't start off the edge of the screen and scrolls in nicely. This is because the "containerWidth" element isn't being updated, and the line is longer (=more width) than the first line. The converse also happens: if the "new" line of text is shorter than the original, it does start nicely - but takes ages to do so. I need a way to completely re-execute the entire function or dynamically change the "containerWidth" var every time new data loads. Can anyone help?

Comment: You don't need to re-execute the whole thing, just update the width with `elWidth = $this.find('.js-marquee:first').width();` in the right place... http://jsfiddle.net/Vbmm5/4/

Comment: If you find the text hangs at the right hand side while the script is getting new text, add `$this.find('#scrollerText').text('');` before the `$.get`.